# Не могу вернуть значение после обработки

Tags: c#

```
public class Cesar
{
    public static string outText = ""; Создаем переменную.


    public static string Crypt(string inText, int k)
    {
        inText.ToUpper();

        if (inText.Length > 0)
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < inText.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < abc.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (inText[i] == abc[j])
                    {
                        //k = Convert.ToInt32();
                        //Convert.ToInt32(k);
                        int temp = j + k;//номер буквы+сдвиг в темп
                        while (temp >= m)//чтобы темп не уходил за рамки алфавита 
                            temp -= m;
                        outText = outText + abc[temp];
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        else
        {
            return "Вы не ввели текст!!!";
        }
        return outText;  // Возвращаем. 
    }
}
```

Возвращает пустое изначальное значение при обьявлении в самом начале.

Comment: сделайте так `inText = inText.ToUpper();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверку параметров лучше проводить сразу и [fail-fast](http://habrahabr.ru/post/218325/).
Если метод возвращает значение, то переменную надо определить внутри метода.
Метод ToUpper возвращает новую строку.
В итоге, класс можно переписать так

```
public class Cesar {
   public static string Crypt(string inText, int k) {
       if(inText.Length == 0) 
          throw new ArgumentException("не ввели текст", "inText");

       string outText = "";
       inText = inText.ToUpper();
       for (int i = 0; i < inText.Length; i++) 
       {
          // ... 
       }   
       return outText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет буду пробывать. я просто де?*)((

Comment: Вместо `inText.Length == 0` лучше `string.IsNullOrEmpty(inText)`.

Comment: @andreycha _"лучше string.IsNullOrEmpty(inText)"_ -- при inText == null будет exception уже при обращении к inText.Length, а на empty и так есть проверка. поэтому я тут не использую метод IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: @Stack ну так и зачем вам потом `NullReferenceException`? Вы же сами ратуете за проверку параметров и fail fast. Значение `null` не укладывается в контракт метода, а значит его тоже нужно сразу проверять.

Comment: @andreycha _"ну так и зачем вам потом NullReferenceException?"_ -- если при вызове Crypt в него передают null, то значит что-то пошло не так за пределами метода Crypt. вот там и получат NullReferenceException, а тратить время в Crypt на лишнюю явную проверку - не надо.

Comment: @Stack да, только о том, что что-то не так за пределами метода, будет легче узнать по `ArgumentException`, а не по `NullReferenceException`. Это такой жыыырный намек: "Чувак, ты мне передал какую-то чушь в качестве аргумента, я не буду с этим работать!" Еще раз: метод работает только с непустыми строками. Это его *контракт*. Перед тем как начать работать со строкой, метод должен убедиться, что входные данные валидны, т.е. соответствуют контракту. `null` не входит в список валидных значений, а потому тоже должен быть сразу отсеян.

Comment: @andreycha _"о том, что что-то не так за пределами метода, будет легче узнать по ArgumentException, а не по NullReferenceException."_ -- а разве из NullReferenceException и stacktrace непонятно, что произошло?

Comment: @andreycha просто представьте, что этот метод надо вызвать 100 миллиардов раз. и в отлаженной программе никогда не будет inText равен null, так для чего его проверять? вроде бы ничего такого. но представьте, что эти 100 миллиардов лишних проверок происходят в облаке, где надо платить за CPU.

Comment: @andreycha если на одну проверку тратится, например, 5 ticks, то для 100 миллиардов проверок - это почти 14 часов CPU потраченных зря.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34677/discussion-between-stack-and-andreycha).

Comment: @Stack одна проверка - это cmp + je. cmp выполняется за один такт. near jump - за два. Так что средний *одноядерный(!)* процессор обработает 100 миллиардов проверок за ... 50 секунд.

Comment: @andreycha [как выяснилось](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27020518#27020518)  в двух комментариях выше - [предположении что этот метод и предложенная вами проверка вызовется 100 миллиардов раз](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484868/484875#comment562801_484875) и следующим **непосредственно за ним** утверждением что [100 миллиардов проверок займут 14 часов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484868/#comment562801_484875) имелись ввиду разные проверки. В первом комментарии он говорит о 100ММ проверок на null. А во втором - о 100MM каких-то **других** проверок.